# Blocking User In smack

Tags: xmpp, smack

I am working on a chat application and i want to block a particular friend from my chat list.Can anyone tell me how can i block a particular user through smack library.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

XMPP defines Privacy Lists in [XEP-16](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0016.html). Smack implemented XEP-16 as [PrivacyListManager](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/PrivacyListManager.html). Documentation and sample code can be found [here](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/documentation/privacy.html).

Comment: I used the Sample Code but i got NullPointer Exception in the following line                                            privacyManager = PrivacyListManager.getInstanceFor(connection);        but connection object is not null.    Plz help me for solving this issue.

Comment: The last link is dead